# In an Angular view, How to prevent a specific input element from validating like other input tags.

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have an input tag which is bound to a scope variable by ng-model. All such input tags get validated and I wrote some custom styling for ng-valid etc. But now I want just one input tag which should not do anything after typing. Old school input tag per se with ng-model binding. How do I prevent the validation on such an element?

```
%form
  %input(ng-model='searchText')
```

I tried the novalidate tag on the form but it is only to prevent HTML5 validation I guess. Could not find anything else.. Any help ppl?

Comment: remove name attribute from that element, but I'm curious to know why you want that?

Comment: What validation properties are being used on the input? If none are set you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: But there is no name attribute in the input tag. It is a search box, hence I dont want to change the look when a user types in it. Its always a valid entry. I have a solution to use '!important' in the css for that tag.. But don't wanna do that since we might have to go for 508 compliance later on

Comment: @charlietfl I am using input validation in all my other input tags and wrote the .ng-valid css in a centralised location. I don't want this input tag to incur the css of .ng-valid.

Comment: @Aditya why you don't give a different class to element and apply css accordingly

Comment: @pankajparkar sure thats what I am trying now.. giving a class(search-container) to the form and using a subclass(search-input) inside the container and writing my css in   `.search-container input.search-input{//custom css}`   Guess there is no simpler way primarily because the ng-valid class is implemented as input.ng-valid by angular.. a simple extra class name will not override the validation css...

Comment: Damn. Thats also not working since angular adds two classes and styles it with both as selectors eg: `input.ng-valid.ng-dirty{//css here}` I am having to add another dummy class 'novalidate' and add that to make the css more specific.

Comment: @Aditya could you please create a fiddle/plunkr, I'd like to help you..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve this by adding you own custom class on that field & write whole custom css in that,

**CSS**

```
input.ng-valid.my-class,  input.ng-valid.my-class:focus{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/59OthB5dxvwfKjqdzbln?p=preview)